# Firing dynamic content using GTM

Tags: javascript, html, google-tag-manager

With GTM  please advise what 'd be the overall process [fm Custom html Tag to JS] or the big picture on how to fire dynamic html code like a div content (with text or image) according a rule such as the referral or cookie variable ?

Scenario : if a visitor come from google organic, then display a specific text  paragraph or a banner at the beginning of the page.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new variable of the referrer type.  Create a variable for the page url.

Create a trigger that fires

- if the referrer starts with google (or www.google)
- the page url does not contain utm_ (campaign parameters for adwords start with utm_)
- the page url does not contain gclid (glcid is the parameter used in Adwords auto tagging)

Attach the trigger to your HTML tag (i.e. "fire tag when visitors comes via google but is not an adwords campaign").

The same principle can be used for other triggers (i.e. check for specific campaign parameters in the url, check if the referrer is empty on the landing page to check for direct visits etc).

Comment: ok tks  so to sum up the workflow is : 2 variables + 1 trigger + 1 custom html  .When you say html tag : "fire tag when visitors comes via google but is not an adwords campaign" is it this tag which contains also   the <div> text or image </div> which ll be inserted dynamically ?

Comment: Hi, sorry for the up, but can i have some more details ? Thanks in advance